# std::promise set_value and thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, language-lawyer

I'm a bit confused about the requirements in terms of thread-safety placed on `std::promise::set_value()`.

The [standard says](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures.promise#15):

> Effects: Atomically stores the value r in the shared state and makes
>   that state ready

However, it also says that `promise::set_value()` can only be used to set a value once.  If it is called multiple times, a `std::future_error` is thrown.  So you can only set the value of a promise once.

And indeed, just about every tutorial, online code sample, or actual use case for `std::promise` involves a communication channel between *2* threads, where one thread calls `std::future::get()`, and the other thread calls `std::promise::set_value()`.

I've never seen a use case where multiple threads might call `std::promise::set_value()`, and even if they did, all but one would cause a `std::future_error` exception to be thrown.

So why does the standard mandate that calls to `std::promise::set_value()` are atomic?  What is the use case for calling `std::promise::set_value()` from multiple threads concurrently?

---

**EDIT:**

Since the top-voted answer here is not really answering my question, I assume what I'm asking is unclear.  So, to clarify: I'm aware of what futures and promises are for and how they work.  My question is why, specifically, does the standard insist that `std::promise::set_value()` must be atomic?  This is a more subtle question than "why must there not be a race between calls to `promise::set_value()` and calls to `future::get()`"?

In fact, many of the answers here (incorrectly) respond that the reason is because if `std::promise::set_value()` wasn't atomic, then `std::future::get()` could potentially cause a race condition.  But this is not true.

The only requirement to avoid a race condition is that `std::promise::set_value()` must have a [***happens-before***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happened-before) relationship with `std::future::get()` - in other words, it must be guaranteed that when `std::future::wait()` returns, `std::promise::set_value()` has completed.

This is completely orthogonal to `std::promise::set_value()` itself being atomic or not.  In a typical implementation using condition variables, `std::future::get()/wait()` would wait on a condition variable.  Then, `std::promise::set_value()` could *non-atomically* perform any arbitrarily complex computation to set the actual value.  Then it would *notify* the shared condition variable, (implying a memory fence with release semantics), and `std::future::get()` would wake up and safely read the result.

So, `std::promise::set_value()` itself does not need to be atomic to avoid a race condition here - it simply needs to satisfy a *happens-before* relationship with `std::future::get()`.

So again, my question is: *why* does the C++ standard insist that `std::promise::set_value()` must actually be an atomic operation, as if a call to `std::promise::set_value()` was performed entirely under a mutex lock?  I see no reason why this requirement should exist, unless there is some reason or use case for multiple threads calling `std::promise::set_value()` concurrently.  And I can't think of such a use-case, hence this question.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a clue, but it's actually four functions `set_value`, `set_exception`, and the `set_..._at_thread_exit` versions that're all effectively mutex'd ([\[futures.promise\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures.promise#2)). The at_thread_exit versions however do not atomically perform the two operations in question (store-thing and make-ready) as the latter operation is deferred until the thread exists.

Comment: I did a little bit of archaeology. The "atomic" wording was not there in the original version ([N2671](http://wg21.link/n2671)), and appeared in a near-total rewording ([N2967](http://wg21.link/n2967)). The `set_..._at_thread_exit` versions were not synchronised until much later ([N3278](http://wg21.link/N3278#1507) resolving [LWG1507](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1507)), so they're not the original motivation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it was not an atomic store, then two threads could simultaneously call `promise::set_value`, which does the following:

1. check that the future is not ready (i.e., has a stored value or exception)
2. store the value
3. - mark the state ready
   - release anything blocking on the shared state becoming ready

By making this sequence atomic, the first thread to execute (1) gets all the way through to (3), and any other thread calling `promise::set_value` at the same time will fail at (1) and raise a `future_error` with `promise_already_satisfied`.

Without the atomicity, two threads could potentially store their value, and then one would successfully mark the state ready, and the other would raise an exception, i.e. the same result, **except** that it might be the value from the thread that saw an exception that got through.

In many cases that might not matter which thread 'wins', but when it does matter, without the atomicity guarantee you would need to wrap another mutex around the `promise::set_value` call. Other approaches such as compare-and-exchange wouldn't work because you can't check the future (unless it's a `shared_future`) to see if your value won or not.

When it doesn't matter which thread 'wins', you could give each thread its own future, and use [`std::experimental::when_any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/when_any) to collect the first result that happened to become available.

---

Edit after some historical research:

Although the above (two threads using the same promise object) doesn't seem like a good use-case, it was certainly envisaged by one of the contemporary papers of the introduction of `future` to C++: [N2744](http://wg21.link/N2744). This paper proposed a couple of use-cases which had such conflicting threads calling `set_value`, and I'll quote them here:

> Second, consider use cases where two or more asynchronous operations are performed in parallel and "compete" to satisfy the promise. Some examples include:
>
> - A sequence of network operations (e.g. request a web page) is performed in conjunction with a wait on a timer.
> - A value may be retrieved from multiple servers. For redundancy, all servers are tried but only the first value obtained is needed.
>
> In both examples, the first asynchronous operation to complete is the one that satisfies the promise. Since either operation may complete second, the code for both must be written to expect that calls to `set_value()` may fail.

Comment: At this point, I don't see a good use-case for multiple threads potentially calling `set_value` on a single `promise`. I *suspect* the atomicity requirement also protects against some more-likely interleaving with the `promise::set_..._at_thread_exit` pair of functions, as they perform the two activities non-atomically. However, that suspicion doesn't give a better answer than this one for me, yet.

Answer (score 8):

> I've never seen a use case where multiple threads might call
>   std::promise::set_value(), and even if they did, all but one would
>   cause a std::future_error exception to be thrown.

You missed the whole idea of promises and futures.

Usually, we have a pair of promise and a future. the promise is the object you **push** the asynchronous result or the exception, and the future is the object you **pull** the asynchronous result or the exception.

Under most cases, the future and the promise pair do not reside on the same thread, (otherwise we would use a simple pointer). so, you might pass the promise to some thread, threadpool, or some third library asynchronous function, and set the result from there, and pull the result in the caller thread.

*setting the result with `std::promise::set_value` must be atomic, not because many promises set the result, but because an object (the future) which resides on another thread must read the result, and doing it un-atomically is undefined behavior, so setting the value and pulling it (either by calling `std::future::get` or `std::future::then`) must happen atomically*

Remember, every future and promise has a **shared state**, setting the result from one thread updates the shared state, and getting the result reads from the shared state. like every shared state/memory in C++, when it's done from multiple threads, the update/reading must happen under a lock. otherwise it's undefined behavior.

Comment: "must happen under a lock" The primitive operations that get used to implement `std::atomic` are generally not "locks"

Comment: Since the reader can't access the shared state's value until it is ready (and blocks in the meantime), and the writer has written the value before the share state becomes ready (releasing blocked readers), how is doing either the read or the write non-atomically going to be undefined behaviour?

Comment: @TBBle that doesn't contradict my answer. "atomic operation" doesn't have to use `std::atomic`. using a lock creates de facto atomic operations, even if consisted out of many non atomic operations.

Comment: @DavidHaim Were you replying to Caleth's comment? Either way, I suspect you might have it backwards. Locks are built out of atomic operations, although usually finer-grained than `std::atomic`. (Or I'm misparsing, and that's what you comment was saying...)

Comment: The behaviour you're describing in this answer is not related to the atomicity of `promise::set_value`, it's the behaviour of the shared state, see [\[futures.state\]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures.state#9)

Comment: @TBBle you're nitpicking unimportant details like how locks are implemented. bottom line is, there are two objects touching a shared state. one writes, one reads. subsequently, these reading and writing have to be atomic, otherwise it's UB. whether the standard also talks about the shared state separately or how this atomicity is implemented is irrelevant. `promise::set_value` must be atomic because if not, `future::get` simply can't work properly, and vice versa.

Comment: The standard promises through things other than the atomicity of `std::promise::set_value()` that it cannot conflict with `std::future::get()`. Specifically, [\[futures.state\]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures.state#9) promises that.

Comment: Because of that, the read and write *cannot* be concurrent, so they do not constitute a [data race](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#20) and hence would not be undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm aware of how promises and futures work, and what their purpose is.  But @TBBle seems to understand what I'm asking.  See my edited question.

Answer (score -1):

These are all good answers, but there's one additional point that's essential. Without atomicity of setting a value, reading the value may be subject to observability side-effects.

E.g., in a naive implementation:

```
void thread1()
{
    // do something. Maybe read from disk, or perform computation to populate value
    v = value;
    flag = true;
}

void thread2()
{
    if(flag)
    {
        v2 = v;//Here we have a read problem.
    }
}
```

Atomicity in the `std::promise<>` allows you to avoid the very basic race condition between writing a value in one thread and reading in another. Of course, if flag were `std::atomic<>` and the proper fence flags are used, you no longer have any side effects, and `std::promise` guarantees that.

Comment: That's not the atomicity of `promise::set_value`, that's the happens-before relationship between `promise::set_value` and `future::get`.